# Function call as a Parameter

Tags: python-3.x

```
def zero():
    return 0

def one():
    return 1

def func(x):
    return 0

func(zero(one()))
```

I want to perform a task inside `func()` based on which function is called as `x`

so in the above-given code, is it possible to know which is the function called as a parameter for `func()` i.e. `one()` or `zero()`

and the function call may or may not stop at `one()`, it could continue like `func(zero(one(two())))`

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail what you're actually trying to accomplish with this? There may be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are returning different values from `zero()` and `one()`, you could do something like this:

```
def zero():
    return 0

def one():
    return 1

def func(x):
    if x == 0:
        print('zero() called')
    elif x == 1:
        print('one() called')

func(zero())
```

Since you are passing only the returned value of `zero()` when you are calling `func(zero())`, it is not possible to get the name of the function inside `func()`.

If you want the exact name of the function, inside func(), you could pass the function object instead and access its name using `__name__` property.
You could also call the function which was passed by calling `x()` inside `func()`:

```
def zero():
    print('0')
    return 0

def one():
    print('1')
    return 1

def func(x):
    x() # Call the function which was passed
    if x == zero:
        print('zero() called')
    elif x == one:
        print('one() called')

func(zero) # Note the lack of '()' after zero
```

Comment: I don't think you should use `__name__` here. For one, it relies on the argument being passed having a `__name__` attribute. This is true for functions, but not for a `__call__`-able class. Instead, you could compare the actual object: `if x == zero:` and `elif x == one:`. But otherwise, I like this approach.

Comment: but I'm not sure about the number of calls inside `func()` to use `__name__

Comment: @NithinKS Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish using this? That will really help to improve the answer.

Comment: It was just a thought, and I started working on that. Trying out different ways. nothing much

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Right. Edited the answer.